# Insert data in mysql colum with spaces with php

Tags: php, mysql, insert, insert-into

I've got a little question about my script, I'm trying to enter a lot of data in my MySQL database but I've got the next problem

I can't enter the data with php because there is a space in one of my column names

here is the code

```
$qw1 = "voornaam, achternaam, straat, postcode, geboortejaar, telefoonnummer, email, ORDER DATE";

$qw2 = "'$vnaam', '$anaam','$straat', $code, $geboorte, $tel, '$email', '$dateandhour'";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO bestellingen ($qw1) VALUES ($qw2)");
```

I hope someone could help me, thanks in forward !

Comment: use backticks - (two answers have appeared while I was writing this). I mean, it should really not be difficult to find this information googling a little bit, or, even better, reading the MySQL manual!

Comment: better yet, rename the field so it DOESN'T have spaces.

Comment: I really searcht on Google but, the backtick don't work ;)

Comment: and it's impossible to use no spaces, because it are my clients who chose the name

Comment: use backticks, not apostrophes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use the sql error ? so you can see what the msitake is .

try this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO bestellingen ($qw1) VALUES ($qw2)") or die(mysql_error());
```

use backticks around this also

```
    `ORDER DATE`
```

Note:  this  `  is not same as this   '

try this

```
   $qw2 = $vnaam .','.$anaam .','.$straat.','. $code.','. $geboorte.','. $tel.', '.$email.', '.$dateandhour ;
```

Comment: This is the syntax error

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER DATE')

Comment: make order date as in my answer with backticks , just copy it and paste it in your code if you dont know what is backticks and single quote. backticks is not same as single quote

Comment: You really helped me out with it ! Thank you so much, i really didn't saw there is a diference between the two

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (`) **tilde symbol**.

```
$qw1 = "voornaam, achternaam, straat, postcode, geboortejaar, telefoonnummer, email, `ORDER DATE`";
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but that didn't really worked my $qw1 now looks like this

voornaam, achternaam, straat, postcode, geboortejaar, telefoonnummer, email, bestellingsdatum, 'Standaard', 'Standaard met drankbonnen'

Comment: use backticks, not apostrophes. The backtick key is next to the "1" key.

Answer (score 0):

Use Backticks

```
 $qw1 = "`voornaam`, `achternaam`, `straat`, `postcode`, `geboortejaar`, `telefoonnummer`, `email`, `ORDER DATE`";
```

Comment: Thanks, for the fast answer, but that does not really work :/

Comment: Know the $qw1 looks like this

'voornaam', 'achternaam', 'straat', 'postcode', 'geboortejaar', 'telefoonnummer', 'email', 'bestellingsdatum', 'Standaard', 'Standaard met drankbonnen'

Answer (score 0):

don't use spaces in column names, but use AS in your query. For example Select orderDate as 'ORDER DATE'