# MySQL add column with spaces in php

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add column to my MySQL-database with spaces.

In terms of SO-questions this is as close as I've come [Insert data in mysql colum with spaces with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621752/insert-data-in-mysql-colum-with-spaces-with-php)

In php MyAdmin I can write the code

```
ALTER TABLE `msrk_krit` ADD `test 1` VARCHAR(255)
```

However in php I am trying to use the code below:

```
mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE msrk_krit ADD 'test 1' VARCHAR( 255 )")
```

But I get this error code:

Error description: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1 VARCHAR( 255 )' at line 1

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: So try backticks like in phpMyAdmin: `ADD \`test 1\``. And then __forget forever__ about such columns' names

Comment: Do not use blanks in table or column names

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using blank spaces in table names. Sometimes you have to handle table and column names with spaces and your code should never be compromised by it. Just use the proper syntax.

Comment: Know that in phpMyAdmin, below a successful query output, there is an option (to the right, just below the query, not the results) to `Create PHP code`. This will generate PHP code for the same query that can then be copy/pasted for use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this:

```
mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE msrk_krit ADD `test 1` VARCHAR( 255 )")
```

Notice that the single quotes around test 1 are actually back ticks, not quote marks.

Honestly though, you should avoid using spaces in your column names, it will be easier to maintain in the long run.

(Documentation: [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php))

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE `msrk_krit` ADD `test 1` VARCHAR(255)")
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE msrk_krit ADD 'test 1' VARCHAR( 255 )")` should be

```
mysqli_query($db, "ALTER TABLE msrk_krit ADD `test 1` VARCHAR( 255 )")
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it, so easy. Darn it!

Comment: No problem. Don't let anyone get you down about spaces in column names. Spaces are completely appropriate.

Comment: You say they're appropriate, but what's your reasoning? Being able to have spaces in table names is not a reason.

Comment: Because they aren't invalid syntax in MySQL and some libraries and some assignment don't allow you to choose your column or table names. Some lazy people don't properly mark up their queries and end up getting broken scripts and embarrassing results.

Comment: Not being invalid doesn't make them appropriate and certainly not appropriate when going by the rest of the query their standard is for underscores (not guaranteed but extrapolation from table name).

Comment: It should still be avoided if possible though. Just because it can be done, doesn't mean it should. There's no reason to use back ticks if there are no spaces. In fact, your code is easier to maintain if you avoid table names with spaces because it's less that can fail when multiple developers get their hands on it. It's not lazy to not add backticks if they're not necessary.

Comment: @Difster `There's no reason to use back ticks if there are no spaces`. This isn't actually true. There are a lot of reserved names special characters with backticks, besides simply spaces. If you have a static, well considered table names in latin characters, help yourself to skip the backticks.